# url can't download csv file

Tags: flutter, csv, dart

When tapping the button **Testing Download CSV file**. Page This site can't be reached will appear. It should be able to download the CSV file when I tap the Test Download CSV File button. Can someone help me with how to solve this problem?

[image: Image no 1]

[image: Image no 2]

This is my code. When I paste this link **https://black.testing.io/assets/assets/files/productlist.csv** into my browser it's can download a CSV file. But when I use this link **http://localhost:7163/assets/assets/files/productlist.csv**. Page This site can't be reached will be shown. Hope someone can help me.

My Code

```
 onTap: () async {
 var url = Uri.base.toString();
 if (url.contains('localhost')) {
 url =
'http://localhost:7163/assets/assets/files/productlist.csv';
 } else if (url.contains('emwatch.testing.io')) {
 url =                                 
'https://black.testing.io/assets/assets/files/productlist.csv';
 }
 if (await canLaunch(url)) {
 await launch(url);
 } else {
 throw 'Could not launch $url';
 }
 },
```

Comment: Do you have a server running on your machine (`localhost`) on port 7163?

Comment: I do not use a server to run on my machine. My system can still run only for this part can not run.

Comment: The main local host on my system is 55756. It's still can work.

Comment: Well, `localhost`  refers to your own machine (IPv4: 127.0.0.1). So if you don't run a (http) server on port 7163 on your machine, any attempts to retrieve a file from that URL will surely fail. This is in contrast to a web address like `https://black.testing.io...` where someone else is running the server.

Comment: Can I setup using windows or need to use xampp?

Comment: XAMPP is most likely overkill for serving a single file. You could use any HTTP server (configured to port 7163). But XAMPP seems to go easy on the installation process, so give it a try. Windows HTTP(S) would probably mean IIS, which I do know nothing about.

Comment: But, of course, to be _served_, there has to be the file `/assets/assets/files/productlist.csv` in the directory of the web server.